# how to identify first element in array of node objects?

Tags: nodes

hook_node_load($nodes, $types) in Drupal 7 takes two arrays as parameters. In the module I'm working on (Drupal 7 port from Drupal 6), just one node of one type is being loaded. I tried $node[0] to specify the first node in the array, but no joy. How do I get at the first node and the first type? There is only one object in each array.

Comment: [array_shift](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-shift.php)

Comment: You should take care with array_shift(), though, since it removes the item from the array. It shouldn't matter for this particular hook, but there are others that pass by reference.

Comment: you could use `$node = reset($nodes);` as well

Comment: Thanks. So, it turns out that the node array is an array of objects. But I guess I still can use this.

Answer (score 1):

$nodes is keyed by the node ID, which you probably won't know in advance. Instead of directly trying to access the first node in the array, iterate over them with a foreach loop.

```
function mymodule_node_load($nodes, $types) {
  foreach ($nodes as $nid => $node) {
    if ($node->type == 'basic_page') {
      ...
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I need to somehow identify the object that is the first node in the array of node objects. I think the reset() function will do that, won't it?